# Ps3 freezes playing Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

For some reason my PlayStation frequently freezes when playing Skyrim, this is most often when I am casting spells, or in combat. As far as I can tell there is no way to drop resolution in the game or the rendering distance which would normally help such a thing. Can anyone help me? Because it’s slowly jacking my ps3 making me have to turn it off by holding down the power button when the game is still on.

Comment: How dusty is the inside of your ps3?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 dusty? Is, is there a way to open it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell your PS3 should be able to handle Skyrim, so here are some recommendations to help fix the problem

Dust is a performance killer for everything PC, consoles, and even phones! Make sure your console isn't clogged. Inspect the intake and outtake vents, take a flashlight and look inside, blow some compressed air into it and see if a cloud of dust comes out. If its really bad you might have to take it apart to completely clean it. Check YouTube for an easy to follow guide.

(P.S. check if your state has a "right to repair" law, meaning you can open up your devices to repair and clean it, even if there are "warranty void if removed" stickers, but if you break anything while repairing it voids your warranty)

Also make sure your PS3 has enough airflow when its running so it doesn't overheat! If a computer detects overheating it will crash the program and/or turn off the computer. Same thing applies to consoles

Another thing to note is that there are some known framerate and crashing issues with digital copies if your hard drive is close to being full

Also any drops or spills could have hurt your PS3 as well